# Проблема с русским алфавитом

Tags: php

Не выполняются много строковых функций, когда передаются русские буквы.

```
    $data = "авыаВв"
echo ucfirst(strtolower($data)); // не работает
    $data = "fdsfsdDfd"
echo ucfirst(strtolower($data)); //работает
```

Comment: @Zow, я вам это тут оставлю: [PHP:Многобайтные строки](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php). А развернутый ответ напишет кто-то другой :)

Comment: Используйте расширение mbstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте вот [тут](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-mb_ucfirst-make-a-strings-first-character-uppercase-multibyte-function/) как работать с UTF.